# Existence of groups of a given order

Tags: abstract-algebra

For groups of order 21 i have found Z21 and Z3×Z7. Also they are isomorphic. I would like to know if there are other groups of order 21 which is not isomorphic to these groups. How many different groups are possible for order 21.

Comment: Are  you familiar with Sylow theory? Then the problem is not so hard. There is in fact only one isomorphism class, namely the one you already mentioned

Comment: A bit different, perhaps, but [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/440792/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that a group of order $ps$ ($p<q$ primes) is cyclic if $q\not\equiv 1\mod p$.

If $q\equiv 1\mod p$, either it is a cyclic group, if it is abelian, or it is a semi-direct product
$$\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z\rtimes_\varphi\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z,$$
where $\;\varphi\colon \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z\to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z)$ is a homomorphism such that $\varphi(\overline 1)$ has order $p$.